# Flexbox Shrink Sidebar to Content Height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a layout where sometimes the sidebar can be significantly taller than the page body. When it excedes the screen height, the sidebar continues expanding vertically.

My code looks somewhat like the following:

```
<div class="fb-col">
    <!-- Headers, etc. -->
    <div class="fb-row">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <!-- Lots of content -->
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <!-- Less content -->
        </div>
     </div>
     <!-- Footers -->
</div>
```

with the following CSS:

```
.fb-col {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.fb-row {
    flex-grow: 1;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
.sidebar {
    width: 25%;
    flex-grow: 0;
}
.main {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

This causes the two elements to not grow vertically (so the main doesn't grow too high), but I can't get the sidebar to limit its height to the document height when the content is too short.

Comment: Are you looking for someting like this? https://jsfiddle.net/x2L4f1zt/1/

Comment: That looks about right. Will that still grow the sidebar if the body is larger than the sidebar?

Comment: Ooh. @HiddenHobbes, almost perfect. Is there a way to make the height of the sidebar respect the parent flexbox? Setting to `100vh` causes it to scroll when the header and footers are added in.

Comment: Could you provide an example please @Bottersnike? Finding it difficult to envision your issue.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes https://i.imgur.com/DWPnub0.png shows it. Basically the sidebar should cut off at the bottom of the show-more button. If the body is less than one page's height, the sidebar should just be big enough to push the footer to the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your goal, I do not believe flexbox (or any CSS) can solve this - without applying absolute dimensions; flexbox can be used to make the *smaller* element(s) bigger, but not vice-versa.

`flex-gorw` and `flex-shrink` size the items based on the *main axis* - for `flex-direction: row`, it's *horizontal*.

The only solution I can think of, is using some JS/jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".sidebar").height($(".main").height());
});
```

```css
.fb-col {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.fb-row {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 align-items: flex-start;
}

.sidebar {
 min-width: 25%;
 width: 25%;
 overflow: auto;
}

.main {
}





/* For illustrative purposes */
.fb-row {
 background-color: #FDD;
}

.sidebar {
 background-color: #DFD;
}

.main {
 background-color: #DDF;
}
```

```html
<div class="fb-col">
 <header><h1>Header</h1></header>
 <div class="fb-row">
  <div class="sidebar">
   <h2>Sidebar</h2>
   <nav>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
        <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
        <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
   <h2>Content</h2>
   <p>Bacon ipsum dolor amet strip steak pork chop porchetta spare ribs ribeye biltong salami tongue. Sirloin ham ball tip, tongue filet mignon cow kielbasa hamburger doner chicken. Pancetta bresaola chuck corned beef hamburger, tenderloin leberkas swine buffalo beef ribs. Filet mignon ball tip t-bone ground round beef ribs. Biltong burgdoggen venison tail hamburger spare ribs buffalo flank meatball tri-tip leberkas.</p>
   <p>Ribeye porchetta kevin, pork sausage strip steak ham chicken pork chop buffalo ground round t-bone cupim pork belly. Fatback flank prosciutto kevin pork chop, pork loin pig. T-bone landjaeger ball tip fatback, shank ribeye picanha pork ground round filet mignon meatball tri-tip jowl. Shoulder meatloaf pork loin meatball ball tip, hamburger kielbasa. Andouille strip steak alcatra ham hock chuck. Cupim chicken buffalo, picanha biltong landjaeger t-bone. Jowl sirloin meatloaf short ribs tongue ground round bacon chuck fatback meatball hamburger picanha turkey kevin pork.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <footer><h2>Footer</h2><small>legal and stuff</small></footer>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your issue, you can try in this way:

```
.fb-col {
    min-height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.fb-row {
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.sidebar {
    width: 25%;
    flex-grow: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.main {
    flex-grow: 1;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

In this way `.sidebar` and `.main` will always have the same height, with a minimum height of 100%.

If it doesn't work add try to add this rule:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem I have is trying to _shrink_ the sidebar down to 100% instead of growing it past 100%.

Comment: so replace min-height:100% with height:100% in sidebar class and add overflow: auto. It should work.